# Estoy usando la gema PG search, con RoR, y busqueda entre varias tablas (multisearchable) la busqueda hace un loop y repite los resultados

Tags: search, pg-search

Ya revise los modelos y estan correctos, el metodo search del controllador funciona bien.

intenté agregar un Uniq en el controllador y en las vistas pero no cambió nada. No sé si será el each con el que hace la busqueda?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.